# Limit for inner Join Table

Tags: postgresql

I have a scenario where I am joining three tables and getting the results.

My problem is i have apply limit for joined table.

Take below example, i have three tables 1) books and 2) Customer 3)author. I need to find list of books sold today with author and customer name however i just need last nth customers not all by passing books Id

```
                   Books            Customer                Authors
              ---------------   ----------------------    -------------
                Id  Name  AID        Id BID Name Date         AID  Name
                 1                 1  1  ABC                1    A1    
                 2                 2  1  CED                2    A2
                 3                 3  2  DFG
```

How we can achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [LATERAL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL).

Sample:

```
SELECT B.Id, C.Name
FROM Books B, 
     LATERAL (SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE B.ID=C.BID ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT N) C
WHERE B.ID = ANY(ids)
  AND Date=Current_date
```

Comment: Thanks Robin, I don't like this Subquery approach. Is their any better way or this is the only way?

Comment: Hmmm... By the way.. do you need just the last record, or do you need last N records?

Comment: N records, Client will pass N.

Comment: Hands down, this is easier to understand than the other answers Google found.